# how compute $\int_a^b xf(x)dx$? such that$ f(a+b-x)=f(x)$

Tags: analysis, integration

let $f(a+b-x)=f(x)$ then how compute $$\int_a^b xf(x)\,dx$$ thanks for any hints

Comment: Let the variable change $a+b-x=y$

Comment: @Maisam Hedyelloo Have you solved this problem yet?

Comment: @Git-gud:yeah i solve it

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo Was the answer helpful? If it was, I suggest you accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: change the variable to $y=a+b-x$.

Comment: Yeah, you got me.